# Setting UILabel to bold?

Tags: swift, label, bold

I'm trying to bold my label, but the label isn't being changed.
Here's the code I'm using:

```
    classLabel.font = UIFont(name: "PingFangHK-Bold", size: 20)
```

Comment: have you added this custom font i plist ?

Comment: Is `UIFont(name: "PingFangHK-Bold", size: 20)` nil? That's the first thing to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the Custom Font to your project? If not you can do so by following this link to Apple's documentation : [Adding a Custom Font to your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app)

You have to make sure the font file is a target member of your app; otherwise, the font file will not be distributed as part of your app.

To find the font names available to your app, do this:

```
for family in UIFont.familyNames.sorted() {
    let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
    print("Family: \(family) Font names: \(names)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the ttf file to the project and than you can use the custom font

Answer (score 0):

You are doing exactly fine and it should work.
But you have not mentioned, if you have used the Font file or not !!

1. Drag the font files to your project and set their target
2. Goto info.plist and add a new row and add **“Fonts provided by application”**
3. Expand the row and next to Item 0 in the Value field enter the name of the font.
   [image: info.Plist Image]